# copy value from one field to another with a unique identifer

Tags: sql, oracle

I'm at a lost once again :)
I've searched and I couldn't find a distinct answer that worked for me, i would love to get some help regarding my question.

I have a table that looks like this:

```
USERID      EVENT               CREATED_DATE
223         USER_CREATED        2018-26-10 00:00:00
223         USER_ACTIVATED      2019-01-01 00:00:00
245         USER_CREATED        2018-21-10 00:00:00
245         USER_ACTIVATED      2019-03-01 00:00:00
261         USER_CREATED        2018-22-10 00:00:00
261         USER_ACTIVATED      2019-09-01 00:00:00
257         USER_CREATED        2018-27-10 00:00:00
```

what I want is to alter the dates of the USER_ACTIVATED events, **I want them to match the relevant USER_CREATED event dates**, the key is the USERID.

for example, for USERID=223, the USER_CREATED date is '2018-26-10 00:00:00' so the USER_ACTIVATED date should be '2018-26-10 00:00:00' as well.

I need an UPDATE query.

a few points:

- there can be only 1 event of each type on each USERID, there are no duplications on the same USERID.
- I have a query that gets all the relevant USERIDs, it's not that relevant I think, but its generally to get al userIds < 0, and the date of the user_created is < SYSDATE-1
- in my example, the USERIDs are one after another, but in reality it's not set in stone that it will be 223, then 245, then 223 again with a different event.

as a final note, the result of the UPDATE should be:

```
USERID      EVENT               CREATED_DATE
223         USER_CREATED        2018-26-10 00:00:00
223         USER_ACTIVATED      2018-26-10 00:00:00
245         USER_CREATED        2018-21-10 00:00:00
245         USER_ACTIVATED      2018-21-10 00:00:00
261         USER_CREATED        2018-22-10 00:00:00
261         USER_ACTIVATED      2018-22-10 00:00:00
257         USER_CREATED        2018-27-10 00:00:00
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this does what you want:

```
update t
    set created_date = (select t2.created_date
                        from t t2
                        where t2.userId = t.userId and
                              t2.event = 'USER_CREATED'
                       )
    where event = 'USER_ACTIVATED';
```

Comment: worked like a charm, trying to grasp what u did, but it works :) thanks very much!

Comment: @Dmoy . . . This is using a correlated subquery to get the created date that you want.

Answer (score 1):

One way to do this update is via CTE/subquery syntax:

```
UPDATE (
    SELECT t1.CREATED_DATE AS CD1, t2.CREATED_DATE AS CD2
    FROM yourTable t1
    INNER JOIN yourTable t2
        ON t1.USERID = t2.USERID
    WHERE t1.EVENT = 'USER_CREATED' AND t2.EVENT = 'USER_ACTIVATED'
)
SET CD2 = CD1;
```